# How to set auto-substitution of multi-domain wildacrd certificates in kubernetes nginx ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster in which nginx works as an ingress controller.

I would like to migrate all applications within a cluster from one domain to another (fro *.foo.xyz to *bar.xyz). To make the transition smooth, I want to support the work of two domains at the same time.

Can I, through the nginx settings (not the Ingress of each application), implement the auto-substitution of the required tls-certificate by domain?

In the examples that I have seen, the certificate is substituted in the individual ingress settings of the applications themselves, which requires at least the secret with the certificate to be added to the namespace of each application.

There are many applications, it will take a lot of time.

Is it possible to solve this problem for me by editing the nginx server configuration and placing certificates only in its namespace, without substituting certificates in the ingress file of each application?

I assumed that this can be done through the configMap of the nginx for kubernetes helm chart through edits `values.yaml` like this:

```yaml
   config:
      http-snippet: |
        server {
          listen 443  ssl http2 ;
          listen [::]:443  ssl http2 ;
          server_name *.foo.xyz;
          ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/foo-xyz-tls/tls.crt";
          ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/foo-xyz-tls/tls.key";
        }

        server {
          listen 443  ssl http2 ;
          listen [::]:443  ssl http2 ;
          server_name *.bar.xyz
          ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/bar.xyz/tls.crt";
          ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/bar.xyz/tls.key";
        }
```

But this example behaved correctly only for one application, as I transferred a group of applications to use a new domain name, I began to substitute *.bar.xyz certificate for *.foo.xyz (it is default in nginx)

I assume that despite the fact that the ingress settings of each application add their own piece to the nginx configuration after the settings from the http-snippet, the certificate settings are pulled from them, because the conditional app.foo.xyz is preferable to *.foo.xyz.